# do group identities of quotient with radical lift?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative Artinian ring and $J(R)$ its radical. Assume that the quotient $R/J(R)$ is a GI-ring.

(definitions that i use: I call a ring $S$ a GI-ring if its unit group, $\mathcal{U}(S)$, satisfy a group identity. And by a group identity a mean a (reduced) word $w(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ such that $w(u_1, \ldots, u_n)=1$ for all $u_i \in \mathcal{U}(S)$).

I was wondering if this group identity lift to $R$, so is $R$ necessarily also a GI-ring?

Since $R$ is artinian we know that $J(R)$ is nilpotent and thus units lift. But is not clear to me if some kinds of group identities of $\mathcal{U}(R/J(R))$ could lift to $R$. 
For example, assume that $R/J(R)$ is finite and thus satisfy the word $x^{n}=1$ with $n$ the cardinality of $R/J(R)$. Do this imply that $R$ is finite (and thus also GI)?

Is there something known? Or a 'easy' answer?

Thanks!

Edit:

$R$ is trivially GI since i supposed commutative. So i have to be more precise in what i had in mind: 
Let $G$ be a finite group, $R$ commutative Artinian with $1$. Then we know that $RG$ is still artinian and $J(RG)$ is nilpotent. Moreover $RG/J(RG) = R/J(R)G$. Assume $RG/J(RG)$ is GI. Do this identity lift to $RG$?.
For example, if $R/J(R)$ is finite and thus $RG/J(RG)$ also, do $RG$ is GI? (even finite?)

Comment: Cross-posted at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153137/do-group-identities-of-quotient-with-radical-lift).

Comment: It looks like an excellent answer has been given at the MO version.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

**Proposition** If $R$ is a unital, associative, Artinian ring and $R/J(R)$ is finite, then $R$ is finite.

*Proof:* $R$ is noetherian by Hopkins-Levitzki, so $J(R)$ is finitely generated over $R$, so $M_i = J(R)^i/J(R)^{i+1}$ is finitely generated over $R$. Furthermore, $J(R)$ acts as 0 on $M_i$, so $M_i$ is finitely generated over $R/J(R)$, so $M_i$ is finite. Since $R$ is Artinian, $M_n=0$ for large enough $n$, and $|R|$ is the product of the orders of the $M_i$ for $i=0$ to $i=n$. $\square$

Note that $RG/J(RG) \neq R/J(R)G$ when $R$ and $G$ have two elements.

Note that when $R$ and $G$ have three elements, then $U(RG/J(RG))$ is a 2-group, but $U(RG)$ is not.

Comment: thank you! This answer indeed helps me :)